# C# - Xml Element with attribute and node value

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-deserialization

I have some Xml that I need to deserialize into an object.  The Xml is:

```
<Person>
  <Type id="1234">Bob</Type>
</Person>
```

and the classes are:

```
public class Person { public Type Type; }
public class Type {
   [XmlAttribute("id")]
   public string id;
   // another property for value "Bob" here, such as:
   public string value;  // ????
}
```

I'd like to deserialize this Xml using `XmlSerializer.Deserialize`, into the concrete objects above (avoiding using XPath, etc.)

What Xml attribute can I decorate the "Type" class with so that I have not only an "id" attribute but also a value ("Bob")?

Comment: Where is the value `"Bob"` being stored in C#?

Comment: that's just it.. it's not right now. I need to know how to represent it in the object, and which XmlAttribute (if any) to mark it with.

Comment: You really need to rename `Type` to `PersonType` or something because it conflicts with `System.Type`

Comment: yes, of course. 'Person' was just a sample class.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You would have to add a property like

```
[XmlText]
public string Text;
```