# How to omit C# object property name node in XML Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

My model classes are:

```
public class Group
{
   public Employee Employee {get;set;}
}
public class Employee {
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

so after serialization my xml looks like this:

```
<Group>
  <Employee>
      <Name>Haley</Name>
  </Employee>
</Group>
```

but I would like it to be:

```
<Group>
  <Name>Haley</Name>
</Group>
```

So is there any attribute etc. to achieve that? I know I can do this using some code, but would be nice if there is some simplier solution. I saw the solution for lists and arrays (using [XmlElement] attribute), but looks like it doesn't work for non collection properties.

Comment: You could rename `<Employee>` to `<Name>` by adding `[XmlElement("Name")]` to `public Employee Employee {get;set;}` as shown in [Serialize/Deserialize different property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19142954/3744182), them serialize the class `Employee` as a string value by marking `Name` with `[XmlText]` as shown in [C# - Xml Element with attribute and node value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6696647/3744182).  Is that what you want?

Comment: I don't think so, because what if there are more than one property inside? Like Name, Surname, Phone etc.? Then I couldn't use attribute just like `[XmlElement("Name")]`

Comment: Then could you clarify your problem please?  Are you saying that `Employee` might have multiple properties and you want to bubble all of them up to the parent?

Comment: In any event I don't think there is a way to bubble multiple elements up to a parent node without using code -- e.g. surrogate properties or a DTO.

Comment: Ok, I thought so. Thanks then.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
public class Group
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Surname")]
    public string surname { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("phone")]
    public string phone { get; set; }
}
```

And just serialize this.